# Activar y desactivar if desde button

Tags: php, condiciones

Es posible activar y desactivar un if desde un botón? lo que necesito es relativamente fácil.. aunque no lo consigo ... bueno vamos al tema lo que quiero es simplemente que cuando pulse un botón muestre el contenido de un if alguna sugerencia ??

```
<button type="button" name="button"></button>
@if()
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>contenido1</td><td>contenido2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
@endif
```

Comment: te sugiero leer [ask] y de paso hacer el [tour] tu pregunta de seguir asi terminará cerrada, pues es amplia y basada en opiniones

Comment: lo voy a leer no entiendo que falta cometí, en todo caso perdonen

Comment: no muestras que llevas, no dejas claro que deseas mostrar y por que debes usar php?

Comment: La verdad es que no se entiende que queres lograr, y tu codigo confunde aun mas.

Comment: lo que quiero es que el if este escondido y cuando pulse el boton se muestre

Comment: y forozamente es con PHP? digo por que eso queda con JS y es mas facil para manipular elementos del DOM

Comment: Definitivamente debes aprender lo que estas haciendo antes de empezar a hacerlo, decir "quiero ocultar un if" tal cosa no existe, lo que tu quieres es ocultar contenido de la página al presionar un boton (que yo recomendaría usar un checkbox por su comportamiento)

Comment: si shadow pero en javascript ando peor que en php.. que ya es bastante por ello intentaba centrarme en php a pesar de tener que recargar la pagina y demás ante todo muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.  LPZadkiel tienes toda la razon estoy aprendiendo y no voy muy avanzada pero supongo que usted si o por lo menos suficiente para dar este tipo de respuesta pero en realidad creo que también esta equivocada ya que no intento ocultar contenido de la pagina simplemente quiero ejecutar un if cuanto pulse un botón y hasta donde llega mi conocimiento los if se ejecutan en el servidor no en la pagina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo con **PHP**:

```
<?php
    $flag = $_GET['flag'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

if ($flag == 1) {

    echo '<a href="?flag=0"><button>Activar</button></a>';

else {

    echo '<a href="?flag=1"><button>Desactivar</button></a>';

}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perfecto esto es justo lo que necesitaba y también es posible realizarlo en Post verdad ?

Comment: Así es, también es posible realizarlo con POST.